# Jest not able to render and test goober styled components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, styled-components

If I pass a goober styled `h1` component to the render method provided by jest, I get this horrible error dump (below). If I pass into the same render method but replace the goober styled component with the native HTML tag `h1`, then it works.

`Title` is a functional component that returns a goober styled `h1` component. `memo` does not play effect the outcome, it is purely the goober styled `<H1 />` component. Which leads me to believe it might be an issue with my Webpack or Babel config?

Please note that the application renders perfectly fine and I am able to interact with it and see the goober styled `<H1 />` component rendered to the screen, it is only jest and tools like react-cosmos that can't seem to make sense of goober.

code snippet

```js
import { memo, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { H1 } from './Typography.style';

interface ITitle {
  title: string;
}

export const Title = memo(({ title }: ITitle): ReactElement => {
  return <H1>{title}</H1>;
});

export default Title;
```

jest code snippet

```js
describe('Title', () => {
  it('renders title', async () => {
    render(<Title title="Title to test" />);

    Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: style.bp.sm,
    });

    await waitFor(
      () => {
        expect(screen.getByText('Title to test')).toBeInTheDocument();
      },
      { timeout: 1000 },
    );
  });
});
```

error dump from jest

```
TypeError: i is not a function

  10 | describe('Title', () => {
  11 |   it('renders title', async () => {
> 12 |     render(<Title title="Title to test" />);
     |     ^
  13 |
  14 |     Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {
  15 |       writable: true,

  at l (node_modules/goober/dist/goober.js:1:2239)
  at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
  at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
  at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049:16)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
  at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
  at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
  at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
  at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
  at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22779:12)
  at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707:5)
  at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670:7)
  at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293:18)
  at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21881:7)
  at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25482:3)
  at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26021:7
  at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22431:12)
  at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26020:5)
  at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26103:10)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:101:25
  at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22380:12)
  at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1042:14)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:97:26)
  at _callee$ (src/test/Typography.test.tsx:12:5)
  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
  at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
  at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
  at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:21:12)

console.error
  Error: Uncaught [TypeError: i is not a function]
      at reportException (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
      at invokeEventListeners (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
      at beginWork$1 (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22779:12) TypeError: i is not a function
      at l (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/goober/dist/goober.js:1:2239)
      at renderWithHooks (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
      at beginWork (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
      at beginWork$1 (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22779:12)
      at workLoopSync (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707:5)
      at renderRootSync (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293:18)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21881:7)
      at updateContainer (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25482:3)
      at /Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26021:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22431:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26020:5)
      at Object.render (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26103:10)
      at /Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:101:25
      at batchedUpdates$1 (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22380:12)
      at act (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1042:14)
      at render (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:97:26)
      at _callee$ (/Users/Development/react-base-project/src/test/Typography.test.tsx:12:5)
      at tryCatch (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
      at Generator.next (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at /Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:21:12)
      at Promise.then.completed (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:390:28)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at callAsyncCircusFn (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:315:10)
      at _callCircusTest (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:218:40)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at _runTest (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:155:3)
      at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:66:9)
      at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:60:9)
      at run (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:25:3)
      at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:167:21)
      at jestAdapter (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:82:19)
      at runTestInternal (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:389:16)
      at runTest (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:475:34)
      at Object.worker (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:133:12)

  at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
  at reportException (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:70:28)
  at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
  at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)

console.error
  The above error occurred in the <l> component:
  
      at l (/Users/Development/react-base-project/node_modules/goober/dist/goober.js:1:2239)
      at /Users/Development/react-base-project/src/components/Typography/Typography.tsx:8:30
  
  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
  Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

  at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20085:23)
  at update.callback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20118:5)
  at callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12318:12)
  at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12339:9)
  at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20736:11)
  at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23426:7)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

The creator of goober responded in the github issues - link: https://github.com/cristianbote/goober/issues/374

You need to call `setup()` at the beginning of the test. In additional, if you are using storybook or react-cosmos, etc. you'll have to call `setup()` at the start too.